# Как перебрать элементы XML в цикле?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xpath

**Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production**

Есть огромная XML и из нее нужно вынуть немного данных на стороне сервера. XML загружаю в XmlType и достаю нужные данные с помощью XPath. Например:

```
declare
  xml XmlType;
begin
  xml := XmlType('
<xml>
  <a>
    <b>0</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <d>
      <e>2</e>
      <e>3</e>
      <e>4</e>
    </d>
    <d>
      <e>5</e>
      <e>6</e>
      <e>7</e>
    </d>
    <d>
      <e>8</e>
      <e>9</e>
    </d>
  </a>
</xml>');
  :r0 := xml.extract('//xml/a/b/text()').getStringVal();
  :r1 := xml.extract('//xml/a/c/text()').getStringVal();
  :r2 := xml.extract('//xml/a/d[1]/e[1]/text()').getStringVal();
end;
```

С единичными элементами проблем нет, они нормально извлекаются, но как быть с повторяющимися? Как выше в примере у меня есть неизвестное количество элементов `d`, каждый из которых содержит неизвестное количество элементов `e`, мне нужно поочередно извлечь каждое и выполнить с ним некоторый серверный метод.

Я могу обратиться по индексу, но я не знаю как получить количество этих элементов, знаю, что в XPath есть встроенная функция `count`, но не понял как ею воспользоваться и поддерживает ли ее моя БД.

Попытка вызвать что-то вроде `xml.extract('count(//xml/a/d)')` приводит к сообщению "Заданное выражение XPATH не поддерживается".

При обращении к несуществующему индексу возникает исключение `SELF_IS_NULL`, может как-то можно этим воспользоваться? Хотя, конечно, я бы не хотел строить логику на исключениях...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функциями [XMLSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions226.htm) или [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm#CIHGGHFB). Например получить все значения `e` в отдельных строках из вашего документа можно таким запросом:

```
select extractvalue(value(E),'e')
  from table(XMLSequence(extract(xml, '//e'))) E
```

Причем можно делать несколько уровней, выбирая отдельные элементы d, а потом получая некоторые значения из них, разворачивая xml в реляционную таблицу. Тот же набор значений получается так:

```
select value(D).getStringVal() d_text, extractvalue(value(E),'e') e
  from table(XMLSequence(extract(xml, '//d'))) D,
       table(XMLSequence(extract(value(D), '//e'))) E
```

В данном случае мы достаем элементы `d`, можем посмотреть элемент целиком или отобрать какие то другие специфичные значения именно этого узла. А так же, добавив в from еще один xmlsequence разворачивать уже элементы выбранного узла.

Если вы хотите работать с этим внутри процедуры, то вы можете написать например:

```
FOR node IN (select value(D) d from table(XMLSequence(extract(xml, '//d'))) D) LOOP
    что то делаем с node.D
END LOOP;
```

Так же для процедурного стиля на просторах интернета нашел такие конструкции:

```
declare
  xml XMLType := XMLType('<b><a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a>'||
   '<a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a></b>');
  x dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  node dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
  value varchar2(32000);
  i pls_integer;
begin
  x := dbms_xmldom.getChildNodes(dbms_xmldom.getNodeFromFragment(xml.extract('//a')));
  for i in 0..dbms_xmldom.getLength(x)-1 loop
    node := dbms_xmldom.getFirstChild(dbms_xmldom.item(x, i));
    value := dbms_xmldom.getNodeValue(node);
  end loop;
end;
```

Пишут, что работает быстрее разбора в запросе. Пример [взят с sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/forum/615648/xmlsequence-bez-ispolzovaniya-sql)

Comment: Спасибо, с пакетом `DBMS_XMLDOM` всё получилось!

Comment: PS: в основном всё в связке с `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR`